# Custom Dictionary reference - Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to work with a custom dictionary that is supposed to save to the user's phone. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting the dictionary to actually save and pull correctly. I think the problem might be (among possible other things) that I have the app reading my custom dictionary in the top level every time it opens as the follows:

```
var allInformationByDate = [
"2016/09/02": DayData(sales: 0, doorsKnocked: 0, milesWalked: 0.00, hoursWorked: 0.00),
"2016/09/01": DayData(sales: 0, doorsKnocked: 0, milesWalked: 0.00, hoursWorked: 0.00)
]
```

I believe it's referencing a struct I made:

```
struct DayData { // Let’s guess
let sales: Int
let doorsKnocked: Int
let milesWalked: Double
let hoursWorked: Double
}
```

Thinking about it more, this is resetting the dictionary every time the user opens the app, when it should be just pulling the custom dictionary as it has been saved.

My question is how do I reference the variable as a variable without putting an equals sign? I think it would be something like this:

```
var allInformationByDate: customDictionary
```

That's just a guess. Anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a top level dictionary instance:

```
var allInfo = [String: DayData]()
```

Then you can update the data by using dictionary subscript:

```
allInfo["2016/09/02"] = DayData(sales: 0,...)
```

Note that using dictionaries in this way will only persist the data as long as application is running. If user exits your application, data will be lost. There are several solutions for data caching, most popular being [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) and [Realm](https://realm.io).